# How can I compute an ANOVA for this mixed-design experiment for error rate?

Tags: r

Using the data frame below, I managed to compute a repeated-measures ANOVA for subject reaction time.  Here is the data frame in question:

```
> str(a)
'data.frame':   2778 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Phase    : Factor w/ 1 level "Test": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Subject  : Factor w/ 17 levels "1","2","3","5",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Group    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Attn","Dist": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Global   : Factor w/ 2 levels "D","S": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Local    : Factor w/ 2 levels "D","S": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ trialtype: Factor w/ 1 level "Dist": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ RT       : num  477 682 720 NaN 604 720 910 707 705 758 ...
 $ ACC      : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE ...
```

And here is the code I used to compute the ANOVA for the reaction times:

```
raw<-read.table('R_notarg_noattn.tdf',header=T)
head(raw)
str(raw)
raw$Subject = factor(raw$Subject)

raw$logrt = log10(raw$RT)  # logorithm of RT
hist(raw$logrt)

tsttrl_nooutliers = subset(raw, logrt>2 & ACC==TRUE)  # take values greater than 2 logs AND where subj responded correctly
attach(tsttrl_nooutliers)  # make column names available as global variables
hist(logrt)
summary(aovrt <- aov(logrt ~ Group*Global*Local + Error(Subject/(Global*Local)), subset=Phase=='Test', data=tsttrl_nooutliers))  # ANOVA table

meanrt=10^tapply(logrt,list( Global=Global, Local=Local, Group=Group), mean)  # de-log and calculate means by condition

par(mfcol=c(1,2))  # c() *combines* values into vector/list; par() sets graphical parameters... equivalent to Matlab's set() ????
barplot(meanrt[,,'Attn'],beside=T,ylim=c(700,1000),xpd=F)
barplot(meanrt[,,'Dist'],beside=T,ylim=c(700,1000),xpd=F)

detach(tsttrl_nooutliers)
```

I'd like to repeat a similar analysis on the error rates, which are coded in the boolean column `ACC`.  I was wondering how I should go about doing this, since this computation requires the intermediate step of calculating error rates by subject per condition.  When I say "condition", I mean to say the unique combination of factors, i.e. $Group, $Global, $Local, $trialtype (selecting only trials where $Phase == Test, as in the previous snippet).

Could anybody point me in the right direction?  In short, I'm unclear on how to obtain the error rates, which I then should have no problem feeding into the `aov` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree that the use of aov() would impose no problems, since you would be moving from analyzing an outcome that is continuous to one that is discrete (multiply observed binomial). Leaving aside the fact that this would normally require Poisson regression or logistic regression, it is possible to aggregate the sum/length of "ACC" within categories of $Subject, $Group, $Global, $Local, and $trialtype. At the moment there is only one level to $trialtype and $Phase, so subsetting would appear unneeded, but if this str() output is on a subset then you could restrict it to those with $trialtype=="Test" by only using `a[a$trialtyp=="Test" , ]` as your dataframe.

```
categ.a <- with( a, tapply(a$ACC, INDEX =list(Subject Group, Global, Local), 
                     FUN = function(x) {
                                   sum(x)/ length(x) }
```

Edit 1: You may want to seek statistical consultation regarding how to approach this study design for a discrete outcome at www.stackexchange.com. You may not even need this step if you set up your glm() or lmer() analysis properly. I would have been thinking that I might try $Subject as a level in a mixed model having ACC==TRUE as the outcome with Poisson errors using an offset of log(length(ACC)).

Edit 2: It is possible that the original approach would be sufficient if you had sufficient numbers in each subject and category that the error rates were "pseudo-continuous", i.e were not largely zeros.

Comment: We do not disagree at all with respect to the use of an ANOVA on the percent correct!  I'm going to have to argue this further with my research director, but for the time being, I'll just humor him.  In any case, I seem to have fixed the issue with the line `meanpc = aggregate(tsttrls$ACC, list(Subject=tsttrls$Subject, Group=tsttrls$Group, Local=tsttrls$Local, Global=tsttrls$Global), mean)`  I'm unclear on the exact difference between these two approaches though.  In any case, I'm accepting your answer and I'll likely refer to it again in the near future.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't do the RT analysis correctly so it's difficult to see how to do the error analysis.  You're not allowed to do an ANOVA on the raw values, you need to aggregate down to conditions first.  After you exclude outliers (what's the justification for these outliers anyway?) you need to then aggregate the rt.

```
agg <- aggregate( RT ~ Group + Global + Local + Subject, data = tsttrl_nooutliers, mean )
```

Then you can do the modelling.  I don't want to tell you how to do the accuracies, although you should be able to figure it out now.  You need to read [Dixon (2008)](http://www.psych.ualberta.ca/~pdixon/Home/resources/Dixon2008.pdf) and [Jaeger (2008)](http://psy2.ucsd.edu/~dhuber/Jaeger_2008.pdf).  ANOVA of accuracies is not recommended and they do a nice job covering the bulk of the reasons.

Comment: My reasons for throwing out the outliers is somewhat immaterial to the question at hand, but we consider that subjects taking a very long time to respond are not representative of those making an effort to perform the task.  Your point is well taken on the aggregation, as I thought this was automatically handled.  You know what they say about assuming...  In any case, thanks for the references.

Comment: No, it's not directly germaine but 7s is just sort of an arbitrary number and quite long for most tasks.  I really meant to ask why you're doing a log transform.  Raw RT's aren't normally distributed but when there's enough of them mean RT's are.  In ANOVA you analyze mean RT's.